# Will asparagus make your pee attract fish?

Tags: vegetables

According to [this website](http://science1.knoji.com/how-to-catch-fish-with-asparagus/):

> He discovered that tinned asparagus was included as part of the
>   emergency ration kit given to American pilots in the Pacific Ocean
>   region, who were working for the US spy organization called the Office
>   of Strategic Services.
>
> The idea of the pilots eating asparagus was a clever one because those
>   who were shot down, or stranded on remote islands had a very valuable
>   way of feeding themselves. Asparagus contains mercaptans which are
>   powerful chemical attractants, and when the vegetable is eaten, these
>   chemicals pass into the urine. The pilots were told to urinate into
>   the water, so that the chemicals would spread through the water and
>   attract fish to the area, making them much easier to catch. This was
>   of course, a valuable food source and the smell of asparagus is
>   present in the urine after just fifteen minutes in many people, or
>   thirty minutes at most.

Was it included in the emergency ration kit and does asparagus attract fish?

Comment: Off the cuff: No - because it would be ***far*** more effective to include dosages of the chemicals itself if that were so effective...

Comment: This one is hard... I've tried to find something about it but without success.

Answer (score 3):

I found an [article](http://resources.metapress.com/pdf-preview.axd?code=x40j232406450310&size=largest) explaining why pee smells after having eaten asparagus. It seems that it is caused by dimethyl sulfide and methanethiol. Therefore, I searched if these elements where able to attract fish. I found this on [Reddit](http://nl.reddit.com/r/todayilearned/comments/rw0xt/til_asparagus_was_once_included_in_the_emergency/):

> dimethyl sulfide is one of the compounds causing the asparagus smell.
>   The wiki says it is also produced by marine phytoplancton and at least
>   one fly eating plant (as a part of the attractant).
>   (scientific [source](http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/bk-1989-0393.ch011) that claim the same thing as wikipedia)

Since we know that phytoplancton is at the base of eating chain, we can conclude that your thesis is *possible*. I also found this on the same Reddit post:

> [This study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC91606/) suggests "that DMSP is a major and hitherto unrecognized
>   source of reduced sulfur for marine bacterioplankton". I'm no expert
>   on the oceanic food chain, and don't know how long the cycle would be,
>   but zooplankton like krill eat bacterioplankton, and are in turn eaten
>   by fish.

In conclusion, I haven't found sufficient evidence supporting the claims that pilot where given asparagus to attract fish, but from biology literature we can infer that it could be possible. That is, however, not a proof.